# Merge every N dataframes in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I have a list with dataframes. I want to merge every 6 dataframes. The way I m doing it is very manual, so I am doing:

```
from functools import reduce
import paandas as pd

list1 = bigList[0:5]
list1DF = reduce(lambda df1,df2: pd.merge(df1,df2,on='index', how = 'outer'), list1)

list2 = bigList[6:11]
list2DF = reduce(lambda df1,df2: pd.merge(df1,df2,on='index', how = 'outer'), list2)
```

and so on, until I merge all of them and then concat,

```
full_df = pd.concat([list1DF, list2DF, ...])
```

Any tips as to how I can automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure – just grab chunks of your big list with a step of `5` and apply what you've been doing anyway:

```
from functools import reduce

big_list = ...
smaller_list = []

for idx in range(0, len(big_list), 5):
    chunk = big_list[idx:idx + 5]
    combined_df = reduce(lambda df1, df2: pd.merge(df1, df2, on='index', how='outer'), chunk)
    smaller_list.append(combined_df)

full_df = pd.concat(smaller_list)
```

Comment: Hi again, just a follow up question (hopefully simple), how can I add the `keys` argument in `concat()`?

Comment: @Beck Um, `pd.concat(smaller_list, keys=...)`?

Comment: Yes but for arbitrary number of dataframes

Comment: I did it like this: keys = []
for i in range(len(smaller_list)):
    str1 = 'ID ' + str(i)
    keys.append(str1)

full_df = pd.concat(smaller_list, keys=keys)

Answer (score 2):

When you must generate many objects, the ideal is to not give them dummy names (obj1, obj2, obj3…).

Collect everything in a list:

```
N = 5
list_DFs = [reduce(lambda df1,df2: pd.merge(df1, df2, on='index', how='outer'),
                                            bigList[i:i+N])
            for l in range(0, len(bigList), N)]

full_df = pd.concat(list_DFs)
```